# Get current row number of a dynamically generated button in a TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Below Is my Code

I tried the method below, but for every button I get the same row number: `0`, I think that is because the first button is default placed at 0th row.

```
 Button btn = sender as Button;
 if (btn != null) {
     row = Grid.GetRow(btn); // And you have the row number... 
 }

 <TreeViewItem Header="Group by:">
    <TreeView Name="TestTreeView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent" 
    BorderThickness="0"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
       <TreeView.Resources>
          <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mdl:TaggedCheckBox}"         
          x:Name="Dispterrs1" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderOfGroup}">              
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Uid="TreeStackPanel" x:Name="TreeStackPanel" >
          <Grid Name="grd_stack">
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
             <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"   Grid.Column="0" Height="8" Width="15" Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="btnUp" Tag="{Binding TagName}"  Click="btnUP_Click">
                <Image Source="..\images\up_arrow.png" />
             </Button>
             <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"   Grid.Column="1" Height="8" Width="15" Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="btnDown" Tag="{Binding TagName}"  Click="btnDown_Click">
                <Image Source="..\images\down_arrow.png" />
             </Button>
             <CheckBox Margin="3,3,0,0" x:Name="cb_TechTerrs"  Grid.Column="2" 
              Tag="{Binding TagName}" 
              IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"></CheckBox>
              <TextBlock Margin="5,3,0,0" x:Name="tbTechTerrs" Grid.Column="4"  Text="{Binding TagName}"></TextBlock>
           </Grid>
         </StackPanel>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.Resources>
   <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
      <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
</TreeViewItem>
```